# .Net DLL registered via RegAsm loads even if the DLL is renamed. How come?

Tags: .net, com, regasm

Our testers are reporting some strange behaviors. We are registering some COM-visible .Net 2.0 components using RegAsm.

For some reason the testers renamed the registered DLL and the strange thing is that the application keeps loading all the components. I didn't expect that!

Does the system monitor the registered files for name changes?

Answer (score 2):

Not knowing the Regasm.exe command line you used makes this a guess, a bit unnecessary.  That you didn't know it mattered is surely already a good explanation why you didn't expect the test outcome.  A simple explanation is that they just renamed the wrong DLL.

Regasm.exe strongly favors you also installing the assembly in the GAC and complains loudly when you don't and use /codebase.  It is a good idea, DLL Hell is a pretty big problem in COM if the client doesn't use a manifest.  So if you did this the right way then it is unlikely they whacked the GAC, it is hard to find and the directory is pretty inaccessible in .NET versions prior to v4.  And, of course, DLL Hell is enough to explain what they observed :)

You narrow it down by looking at the registry entries with Regedit.exe.  If you don't know where to look then you can use SysInternals' ProcMon utility.  Use it while you run Regasm.exe, you'll see it write the registry keys.  If you don't use the [Guid] attribute on ComVisible classes, the safe way, then these places you'll look in the registry depend on the version of your interface and class.  Making changes to them changes the auto-generated guid.